# JAXB Code Generation with compile Errors

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb

when i generate classes with JAXB in eclipse, with the following xsd, i got the following compilation errors.

Class SubstitutionIndicator

```
@XmlType(name = "SubstitutionIndicator")
@XmlEnum
public enum SubstitutionIndicator {
```

Error

Cannot resolve XML type definition with namespace 'http://www.text.com' and name 'SubstitutionIndicator' in this context

Class OrderedArticle

```
@XmlElement(name = "RequestedDeliveryDate")
```

Error Cannot resolve XML element declaration with namespace '' and name 'RequestedDeliveryDate' in this context

Class MasterOrderCycle

```
 @XmlElement(name = "SubstitutionIndicator")
 protected SubstitutionIndicator substitutionIndicator;
```

Error Cannot resolve XML element declaration with namespace '' and name 'SubstitutionIndicator' in this context

Class InquiryA2

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "inquiry_A2")
public class InquiryA2
```

Cannot resolve XML type definition with namespace 'http://www.text.com' and name 'inquiry_A2' in this context

I see should be something related to namespaces but namespaces are defined in the xsd and i can't understand why it happens.

**XSD**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:ew="http://www.text.com"
    xmlns:px="http://www.text.com"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    targetNamespace="http://www.text.com">
  <xs:element name="inquiry_A2" type="ew:inquiry_A2"/>
  <xs:complexType name="inquiry_A2">
    <xs:complexContent>
      <xs:extension base="ew:MasterOrder"/>
    </xs:complexContent>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="MasterOrder">
    <xs:complexContent>
      <xs:extension base="px:MasterOrderCycle"/>
    </xs:complexContent>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:simpleType name="AgencyCode">
    <xs:restriction base="px:String..3">
      <xs:enumeration value="1"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="2"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="3"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="4"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="5"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="6"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="7"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="8"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="9"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="10"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="11"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="12"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="13"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="14"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="15"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="16"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="17"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="18"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="19"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="20"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="21"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="22"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="23"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="24"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="25"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="26"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="27"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="28"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="29"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="30"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="31"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="32"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="33"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="34"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="35"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="36"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="37"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="38"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="39"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="40"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="41"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="42"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="43"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="44"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="45"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="46"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="47"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="48"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="49"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="50"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="51"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="52"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="53"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="54"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="55"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="56"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="57"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="58"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="59"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="60"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="61"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="62"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="63"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="64"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="65"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="66"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="67"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="68"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="69"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="70"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="86"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="87"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="88"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="89"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="90"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="91"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="92"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="93"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="94"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="95"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="96"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="97"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="98"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="99"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="100"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="101"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="102"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="103"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="104"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="105"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="106"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="107"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="108"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="109"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="110"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="111"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="112"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="113"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="114"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="115"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="116"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="117"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="118"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="119"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="120"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="121"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="122"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="123"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="124"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="125"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="126"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="128"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="129"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="130"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="131"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="132"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="133"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="134"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="135"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="136"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="137"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="138"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="139"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="140"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="141"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="142"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="143"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="144"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="145"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="146"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="147"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="148"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="149"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="150"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="151"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="152"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="153"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="154"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="155"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="156"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="157"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="158"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="159"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="160"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="161"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="162"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="163"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="164"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="165"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="166"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="167"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="168"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="169"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="170"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="171"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="172"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="173"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="174"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="175"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="176"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="177"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="178"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="179"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="181"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="182"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="183"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="184"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="ZZZ"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
  <xs:complexType name="ArticleIdentification">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="BuyersArticleID" type="px:BuyersArticleID" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="ManufacturersArticleID" type="px:ManufacturersArticleIDType" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="EANUCCArticleID" type="px:EANUCCArticleIDType" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="BuyerParty">
    <xs:complexContent>
      <xs:extension base="px:PartyType"/>
    </xs:complexContent>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:simpleType name="BuyersArticleID">
    <xs:restriction base="px:String..35"/>
  </xs:simpleType>
  <xs:simpleType name="Campaign">
    <xs:restriction base="px:String..12"/>
  </xs:simpleType>
  <xs:complexType name="Consignee">
    <xs:complexContent>
      <xs:extension base="px:PartyType"/>
    </xs:complexContent>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="CoreArticle">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="ArticleIdentification" type="px:ArticleIdentification" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="CustomerReference">
    <xs:complexContent>
      <xs:extension base="px:ReferenceType"/>
    </xs:complexContent>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:simpleType name="DateTime">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:maxLength value="10"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
  <xs:simpleType name="Decimal..15">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:decimal">
      <xs:totalDigits value="15"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
  <xs:simpleType name="DocumentID">
    <xs:restriction base="px:String..35"/>
  </xs:simpleType>
  <xs:simpleType name="EANUCCArticleIDType">
    <xs:restriction base="px:String..35">
      <xs:maxLength value="14"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
  <xs:complexType name="ElectronicDocumentType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="DocumentID" type="px:DocumentID" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="Variant" type="px:Variant" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:simpleType name="Indicator">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:maxLength value="1"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
  <xs:simpleType name="LineID">
    <xs:restriction base="px:String..6"/>
  </xs:simpleType>
  <xs:simpleType name="ManufacturersArticleIDType">
    <xs:restriction base="px:String..35"/>
  </xs:simpleType>
  <xs:complexType name="MasterOrderCycle">
    <xs:complexContent>
      <xs:extension base="px:ElectronicDocumentType">
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="TransportPriority" type="px:TransportPriorityType" minOccurs="0"/>
          <xs:element name="Campaign" type="px:Campaign" minOccurs="0"/>
          <xs:element name="SubstitutionIndicator" type="px:SubstitutionIndicator" minOccurs="0"/>
          <xs:element name="CustomerReference" type="px:CustomerReference" minOccurs="0"/>
          <xs:element name="BuyerParty" type="px:BuyerParty" minOccurs="0"/>
          <xs:element name="OrderingParty" type="px:OrderingParty" minOccurs="0"/>
          <xs:element name="Consignee" type="px:Consignee" minOccurs="0"/>
          <xs:element name="PaymentTerms" type="px:PaymentTerms" minOccurs="0"/>
          <xs:element name="OrderLine" type="px:OrderLine" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="OrderedArticle">
    <xs:complexContent>
      <xs:extension base="px:CoreArticle">
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="RequestedDeliveryDate" type="px:RequestedDeliveryDate" minOccurs="0"/>
          <xs:element name="RequestedQuantity" type="px:RequestedQuantity" minOccurs="0"/>
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="OrderingParty">
    <xs:complexContent>
      <xs:extension base="px:PartyType"/>
    </xs:complexContent>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="OrderLine">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="LineID" type="px:LineID" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="OrderedArticle" type="px:OrderedArticle" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:simpleType name="PartyID">
    <xs:restriction base="px:String..20"/>
  </xs:simpleType>
  <xs:complexType name="PartyType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="PartyID" type="px:PartyID" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="AgencyCode" type="px:AgencyCode" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:simpleType name="PaymentMethod">
    <xs:restriction base="px:String..10">
      <xs:enumeration value="C"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="K"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
  <xs:complexType name="PaymentTerms">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="PaymentMethod" type="px:PaymentMethod" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="QuantityType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="QuantityValue" type="px:QuantityValue"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:simpleType name="QuantityValue">
    <xs:restriction base="px:Decimal..15"/>
  </xs:simpleType>
  <xs:complexType name="ReferenceType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="DocumentID" type="px:DocumentID"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:simpleType name="RequestedDeliveryDate">
    <xs:restriction base="px:DateTime">
      <xs:pattern value="\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
  <xs:complexType name="RequestedQuantity">
    <xs:complexContent>
      <xs:extension base="px:QuantityType"/>
    </xs:complexContent>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:simpleType name="String..10">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:maxLength value="10"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
  <xs:simpleType name="String..12">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:maxLength value="12"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
  <xs:simpleType name="String..20">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:maxLength value="20"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
  <xs:simpleType name="String..3">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:maxLength value="3"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
  <xs:simpleType name="String..35">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:maxLength value="35"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
  <xs:simpleType name="String..4">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:maxLength value="4"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
  <xs:simpleType name="String..6">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:maxLength value="6"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
  <xs:simpleType name="String1">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:length value="1"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
  <xs:simpleType name="SubstitutionIndicator">
    <xs:restriction base="px:Indicator">
      <xs:enumeration value="Y"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
  <xs:simpleType name="TransportPriorityType">
    <xs:restriction base="px:String..4">
      <xs:enumeration value="REPL"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="RUSH"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="SEAS"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
  <xs:simpleType name="Variant">
    <xs:restriction base="px:String1"/>
  </xs:simpleType>  
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: That XSD generates JAXB just fine (which compiles cleanly) for me in Eclipse.     Are you sure you're using that exact XSD?   If so, maybe include more details about what JAXB options you're using in your Eclipse JAXB generation.

Comment: all the defaults and strict validation. JAXB version 2.2